# Adjusting size of plot title separately

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot where I would like to specify the size of the titles on the x and y axis and the top separately. How can this be done?

```
  plot+ theme(axis.text=element_text(size=9),
          axis.title=element_text(size=9),
          axis.line = element_line(size=0.25),
          axis.ticks=element_line(size=0.25),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank(),
          legend.position="none" ,
          legend.direction="vertical", 
          legend.title=element_blank(),
          legend.text=element_text(size=9), 
          legend.background=element_blank(), 
          legend.key=element_blank())+labs(title='this',x='that',y='other')
```

Right now this code plots the x and y axes in the same size and the title in much larger font. How can I adjust the size of the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be one answer.

You can specify `theme(plot.title=element_text(size=9))` so your title would be same size as others.

The working example:

```
x <- seq(1,10,1)
y <- dnorm(x,mean=10,sd=0.5)

qplot(x,y) + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=9),
                         axis.title=element_text(size=9),
                         axis.line = element_line(size=0.25),
                         axis.ticks=element_line(size=0.25),
                         panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                         panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                         panel.border = element_blank(),
                         panel.background = element_blank(),
                         legend.position="none" ,
                         legend.direction="vertical", 
                         legend.title=element_blank(),
                         legend.text=element_text(size=9), 
                         legend.background=element_blank(), 
                         legend.key=element_blank(),
                   plot.title=element_text(size=9))+
    labs(title='this',x='that',y='other')
```

Notice I added the last line on theme. I hope this helps.